# How to get current SPListItem from web part on edit form?

Tags: 2010, web-part, edit-form

It seems like there should be a way to do this, but I haven't found anything.  Do I need to use the url to try and extract this information or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you already tried `SPContext.Current.ListItem`?